# Save data array using serializers in rest framwork in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Save data array using serializers in rest framwork in django.

I created an array of data to save to the database. Fields are populated and are compatible with serialization. But the error below occurs.

Thanks for listening

```
data = [{'nome': 'NILVA HELENA DA SILVA', 
        'cnpj_emitente': '11306471000149'},

        {'nome': 'NILVA HELENA DA SILVA', 
        'cnpj_emitente': '11306471000149'}]

xml_create = XMLCreateSerializer(data=data)


result 
Non_field_errors ["Invalid data. Needed a dictionary but received list."]
```

How can I save an array of data using serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [stated in docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects), use `many=True`

```
xml_create = XMLCreateSerializer(data=data, many=True)
```

Comment: Its Work! Thank you very much.